# Trouble installing pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-15.10

I am running ubuntu 15.10 and I have python 3 installed.
But I don't have pip3 installed

I tried to install pip3 using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

But I get the following error:

```
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-Z930:~/Desktop/Telethon-master$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libssl-dev
  libssl-doc libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream
  node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
  node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid
  node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json
  node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-underscore node-which python-colorama python-distlib python-requests python-wheel zlib1g-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.4-dev python3-colorama python3-dev python3-distlib python3-setuptools
  python3-wheel python3.4-dev
Suggested packages:
  python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.4-dev python3-colorama python3-dev python3-distlib python3-pip python3-setuptools
  python3-wheel python3.4-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libexpat1
1 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 207 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 52.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libpython3.4-dev libpython3-dev python3-colorama python3.4-dev python3-dev python3-distlib
  python3-setuptools python3-pip python3-wheel
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main libexpat1 amd64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main libexpat1 amd64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libpython3.4-dev amd64 3.4.3-9ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main libexpat1-dev amd64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.15.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libpython3-dev amd64 3.4.3-4ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe python3-colorama all 0.3.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main python3.4-dev amd64 3.4.3-9ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main python3-dev amd64 3.4.3-4ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe python3-distlib all 0.2.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main python3-setuptools all 18.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/universe python3-pip all 1.5.6-7ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main python3-wheel all 0.26.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1_2.1.0-7ubuntu0.15.10.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-7ubuntu0.15.10.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.4/libpython3.4-dev_3.4.3-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/libpython3-dev_3.4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-colorama/python3-colorama_0.3.3-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.4/python3.4-dev_3.4.3-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-dev_3.4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/distlib/python3-distlib_0.2.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-setuptools/python3-setuptools_18.4-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_1.5.6-7ubuntu1.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wheel/python3-wheel_0.26.0-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Im a newbie to python and ubuntu. what am I doing wrong here?
Also im not using a proxy server, im connected to the internet directly.

Thank you

EDIT: I tried running sudo apt-get update and I get the following error:

```
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-Z930:~/Desktop/Telethon-master$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wily InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security Release.gpg
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease                 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security Release                    
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease
Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Sources [762 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources/DiffIndex         
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily Release.gpg
Get:2 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main amd64 Packages [964 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex    
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release.gpg
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main i386 Packages [968 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex      
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports Release.gpg
Get:4 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex             
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily Release                                         
Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release                          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:6 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources/DiffIndex
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get:8 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Get:9 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources/DiffIndex                   
Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex                     
Get:11 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex       
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                 
Get:12 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:13 https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en [162 B]                 
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wily/main Translation-en                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                           
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                     
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                       
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                     
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex                                                         
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex                                                   
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex                                                     
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex                                                   
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                  
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                            
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Fetched 2,694 B in 2min 3s (21 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your network connection

Comment: Your apt sources are broken... Not a Python problem

Answer (score 4):

You will have to set your APT network mirrors to another one, as there are no `wily` packages on ci.archive.ubuntu.com, as you can see here: http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Just remove the `ci.` from all links to read `archive.ubuntu.com`, do a `sudo apt-get update` and you should be set.

As the current long-term support  Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, you should also consider updating. How to do that and what to expect is best discussed over at https://askubuntu.com/, where this question should have appeared in the first place, because it has nothing to do with code or programming but an operating system.

Comment: Sure. If you are looking forward to constantly updating your work environment. LTS releases are supported for 5 years and provide, well, long term stability.

Comment: As a developer, I'm not really concerned with stability

Comment: OP said: "I'm a newbie to Python and Ubuntu."